# USB Sound card doubling sounds

Tags: usb, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

I've recently purchased a beefier machine and have decided to install Ubuntu Studio 23.10. My previous machine runs Ubuntu 22.04 and works fine.

I was able to get my external sound cars (M-Audio Fast Track Ultra) installed, but when I try to use it, I get a echo/reverb effect almost as if the signal is being sent there twice.

If I use the HDMI speakers on my monitor, I don't have this problem, so I think it must have something to do with the USB configuration.

I've tried switching to PulseAudio from Pipewire, but I still have the same issue.

Is it possible that maybe multiple sound systems, ALSA, Jack, Pulse Audio, Pipewire, are communicating to the device simultaneously?

Any help would be appreciated.